# ASP.NET C# open dialog box from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to open a Jquery dialog box from a server side script in ASP.NET C#.

Here is what the dialog box looks like in Jquery:

```
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({            
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,

        buttons: {
            "Register": function () {

            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');                    
            }
        }
    });
```

I need the code to call this dialog box from the code behind I am trying to us something like;

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Pop", " $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');", true);
```

Need help in using the most appropriate way to open a dialog box from the code behind as what I have does not work. Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the dialog first before calling open. For example:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Pop", "$(function(){$('#dialog-confirm').dialog();$('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');});", true);
```

The JS works like this:

```
$(function(){ //Page is ready
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog(); //init dialog
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); //open dialog
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of the 2nd parameter. "Pop"?

Comment: I get the following message: Error 311 No overload for method 'RegisterStartupScript' takes 4 arguments

Comment: Thank but still nothing happens when I run the revised code. Do I need to put the following client side code: $('#dialog-confirm').dialog(); //init dialog
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); //open dialog Or is that handled in the ScriptMananager code.

Comment: Wait. Do you have <div id="dialog-confirm"></div> in your HTML? You need this.

Comment: Yes, I have the following at the top:<div id="dialog-confirm">Please note, in order to view the content you must be registered.</div>. Actually the modal does comes up just fine if I switch it to autoOpen: true without making use of the server side code. It just that can't it to work from the server side code in which case I took away the autoOpen: true. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. JUST CAN"T GET THIS TO WORK FROM SERVER SIDE SCRIPTING.